# Custom html helper drop down list

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this snippet :

```
@Html.DropDownList("consultations", Model.ConsultationsTruncated, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "consultations" })
```

the displayed texts are truncated :

**For Example**

> string s = "Hello everybody" ==> Text ="Hel..." and Value = ""Hello
>   everybody"

I'd like to replace this implementation by a similar using Extension Method :

```
 public static class TruncateDropDownList
{

    public static DropDownList TruncateDropDown(this HtmlHelper helper, ListItem[] values)
    {
        DropDownList drop = new DropDownList();
        drop.Items.AddRange(values);

        List<SelectListItem> Textes = new   List<SelectListItem>() ;
        foreach (ListItem item in values)
        {
            SelectListItem selItem = new SelectListItem();
            if (item.Text.Length <= 20) selItem.Text = item.Text;
            else selItem.Text = item.Text.Substring(0, 20) + "...";
            Textes.Add(selItem);
        }

        return drop;

    }
}
```

this method implementation is missing :

1. dropDownList name attribute
2. Css Attribute
3. Make selected texts and values as in the first one

How can I complete this method to accomplish this task??

Comment: Your helper needs to return `MvcHtmlString` and your not passing a property name to the method-

Comment: @Downvoter What are your reasons!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have added parameter in your extension method for html attributes:

```
public static MvcHtmlString TruncateDropDown(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, ListItem[] values, Object htmlAttributes)
{

   List<SelectListItem> Textes = new List<SelectListItem>();
   foreach (ListItem item in values)
   {
       SelectListItem selItem = new SelectListItem();
       if (item.Text.Length <= 20) 
          selItem.Text = item.Text;
       else 
          selItem.Text = item.Text.Substring(0, 20) + "...";
                Textes.Add(selItem);
   }

   return System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownList(helper,
                                                            name, 
                                                            Textes,
                                                            htmlAttributes);

}
```

Comment: the variable `expression` is missing

Comment: the variable `attributes` also :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by leveraging the existing HtmlHelper for DropDownList. It would look something like this:

```
public static class TruncateDropDownList
{
    public static MvcHtmlString TruncateDropDown(this HtmlHelper helper, string id, ListItem[] values, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> Textes = new   List<SelectListItem>() ;
        foreach (ListItem item in values)
        {
            SelectListItem selItem = new SelectListItem();
            if (item.Text.Length <= 20) selItem.Text = item.Text;
            else selItem.Text = item.Text.Substring(0, 20) + "...";
            Textes.Add(selItem);
        }

        return helper.DropDownList(id, values, htmlAttributes);
    }
}
```